# Are there any differences in the drop system for Free and Premium accounts?

Tags: team-fortress-2

So recently I got a premium account in tf2. Does that change what type of items I get now in the weekly random drop? If so, what type of items should I expect?

Comment: https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Account_types

Comment: *Hats*... Hats **and MOAR HATS**... Okay. I exaggerated a little. (Chance is about 1 in every 200-or-so normal drops on average) | But you also get better items too, like [rares; non-set/some purchase-only items as Uniques](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Crafting#Rare_items). Also, there isn't much details on what actually drops; only the category of items.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Free2Play FAQ](http://www.teamfortress.com/freetoplay/faq.php), Free users can only obtain **Standard** items (in item drops, these are just simple weapons and crates), whereas a Premium user can obtain Standard along with **Rare and Cosmetic** items, such as hats/miscellaneous cosmetics, a certain limited range of Paint Cans and tools.

A full list of obtainable items and more information can be found on [this page](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Item_drop_system) of the TF2 wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes, there are slight differences.

Premium account types can get hat drops alongside the usual weapon drops, along with paint can drops, name tag, and other misc. items.

Answer (score -2):

No, the only difference in the accounts are that premium accounts means that you can trade TF2 items from your weekly drops, but in the free accounts that is not possible. Also, you get a Mann Co. hat for getting a premium account.

Comment: Wrong, actually. The item drop system differs between free and premium accounts.

Comment: As Texenox said. See his answer as a two-way learning experience - you learn more about TF2's account and drop system, as well as how an answer should be written - with a source to cite that isn't based on how little you may actually know.